# Nuts soaked and dried. Fridge or not?

Tags: food-safety, storage-method, nuts, soaking

I usually soak nuts overnight. I usually do this with walnuts, almonds, and hazelnuts. Then I dry them at low temperatures. After that, is it better to store them in the fridge or outside if I want a long shelf life?

Comment: There have been comments asking why the OP is soaking the nuts. It turned out to be a health-related reason, which devolved into a discussion on the correctness of their health beliefs. Please do not ask this again - we don't need this discussion, and it isn't really needed for an answer anyway.

Comment: Are they fully dried again, or just enough to get the surface water off (you can check the weight before and after the process)?  This could affect the keeping properties

Comment: They are fully dried

Answer (score 0):

A study ("The Effect of “Activating” Nuts on Fat and Mineral Content" https://ourarchive.otago.ac.nz/handle/10523/9017) which soaked and then dried nuts at low temperatures found that these activated nuts (except for whole almonds) do have less fat, and we know that the oxidation of fat produces rancid flavors and odors. However, there is still a significant amount of fat left to go rancid after soaking and drying, so there seems to be no reason not to refrigerate them, when that is known to increase their life.

Comment: There's like 1 sentence in here that actually answers the question, buried under discussion of (off-topic) heath benefits. Would be nice if it were inverted to bring the relevant part to the fore.